# How to handle click event of parent of iframe in javascript (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe

My goal is to build a component in React with an iframe and be able to handle the click event on that iframe. However, my `onClick` event doesn't fire, only when I click on the parent div that is outside the scope of the child iframe it contains. Is there any solution to help me with this? Thanks.

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div onClick={() => alert("Testing")}>
        <iframe
          src="https://google.com.vn"
          title="stackoverflow"
          style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
        />
      </div>
   </div>
 );
}
```

My sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/onclick-on-parent-of-iframe-jjigu?file=/src/App.js

Comment: It'd be nice to have some part of the code in the question. Links can go dead in the future.

Comment: There's no solution to this unless you also control the domain of the iframe. For security reasons, access to iframe content is basically zero if they're showing a page from a different domain.

Answer (score 2):

As the other commenter suggested, for security reasons you cannot listen for events inside the iframe from another domain.

Depending on what you need to accomplish, you could attach `focus` and `blur` event listeners to the window and use that as a proxy for when someone focuses the iframe.

```
import * as React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

function handleBlur() {
  console.log("document blurred");
}

function handleFocus() {
  console.log("document focused");
}

export default function App() {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("focus", handleFocus);
    window.addEventListener("blur", handleBlur);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("focus", handleFocus);
      window.removeEventListener("blur", handleBlur);
    };
  });
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <iframe
        src="https://example.com"
        title="stackoverflow"
        style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

One could go further to check if the iframe is focused by checking the `document.activeElement` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/activeElement

Comment: Thanks! So how about in the case that iframe and parent has the same domain, what should I do?

Comment: If it's the same domain, you can access the document through `contentWindow` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentWindow and attach listeners wherever you want.